# Amazon MWS API:Retrieve multiple Images uploaded by Seller c#

Tags: c#, image, c#-4.0, amazon-web-services

I  am working with amazon MWS API,
Is there a way to get the image link for Product in an inventory UPLOADED by Seller via SKU/ASINs.

I need to get those products images which are uploaded by the Seller , not what is showed by Amazon.,I am Ok if i get a report which return all images of all SKU/ASINs.

Here is a Couple of things, which i have tried:

I tried to use GetMatchingProduct from MWS API, Currently what I am getting in return is a single image as below:

```
<ns2:SmallImage>
<ns2:URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images_abc.jpg</ns2:URL>
<ns2:Height Units="pixels">75</ns2:Height>
<ns2:Width Units="pixels">51</ns2:Width>
</ns2:SmallImage>
```

I have multiple images on that product, its showing only single image

Secondly, I tried  MWS Report API for listing the inventory and , all other columns are loading properly ,but there is no image url under image-url column , The Result of this file is  in the tab delimited format

Any one has experience with MWS API please help me with this...

Thanks

Fez K

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the list of images is available through MWS.  You can however retrieve it through the separate Product Advertising API's [ItemLookup](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemLookup.html) endpoint using a response group of [Images](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/RG_Images.html).

Since you mentioned C#, you may find the [Nager.AmazonProductAdvertising](https://github.com/tinohager/Nager.AmazonProductAdvertising) NuGet package helpful in accessing the PA-API.